# Best way to return full object made from data from different APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Im working on an app that mainly is a large form that contains several dropdowns. These dropdowns should
populate with some data from the DB. The app has a server with Express that it works as a proxy: I call it from the front end
and then that server calls some external API's, format the info and then send them back to the front.

Im thinking on having on the Backend a route like "/dropdown" call that route from the front end. And once I get the data (I would like to receive it like this)

```
data: {
dataForDropdown1:[data],
dataForDropdown2:[data],
dataForDropdown3:[data],
dataForDropdown4:[data],
...etc
}
```

store it on Redux and call them with a selector and populate all the dropdowns required.

The problem is on the server. I need to get that info from different APIs so in the route in Express I was thinking on use something like

```
Promise.all([promisefetchUrl1],[promisefetchUrl2],[promisefetchUrl3],...etc)
```

but I don't know how to format like the object above, because as I understand Promise.all doesn't have an order it just returns the info with the first promise resolved, then the second, etc so it would be hard to know
which info is which.

I was thinking on using async await but its way too dirty, like this:

```
const info1 = await fetch(url1)
const info2 = await fetch(url2)
const info3 = await fetch(url3)
const info4 = await fetch(url4)
etc
```

then return it like this

```
const data = {
dataForDropdown1:info1.data,
dataForDropdown2:info2.data,
dataForDropdown3:info3.data,
dataForDropdown4:info4.data
...etc
}
```

any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Promise.all doesn't have an order it just returns the info with the first promise resolved, then the second, etc so it would be hard to know which info is which.

It does have an order - the first element in the resolve array will correspond to the first Promise in the array passed to `Promise.all`, etc, regardless of the order in which the promises resolve.

Use:

```
const results = await Promise.all([
  getData(promisefetchUrl1),
  getData(promisefetchUrl2),
  getData(promisefetchUrl3),
  getData(promisefetchUrl4), // this could be made less repetitive
]);
const data = {
  dataForDropdown1: results[0],
  dataForDropdown2: results[1], 
  dataForDropdown3: results[2],
  dataForDropdown4: results[3],
};
```

where `getData` takes the URL and returns a Promise that resolves to the data corresponding to the URL.